# different between SSIS and SQL Agent Job

Tags: ssis, sql-agent-job

I am new on this whole SQL things. What's SLQ Agent Job and what's the different with SSIS Package? Aren't they same thing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Integration Services is a very powerful tool. With SSIS packages one can do all sorts of magic, see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-packages
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/218914/Steps-to-Create-your-First-SSIS-Package

SQL Agent Jobs are there for executing pre-defined scripts, commands, queries and also - get this! - SSIS packages! You can even schedule its execution. How cool is that?! Here's a list of things it can do (in SQL Server 2016):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A SSIS package when run in Visual Studio is run as the person executing the package.

A SSIS package run from Agent is run as the Agent (usually some type of service account) or can be defined as a different user via proxy.

Most environments only allow direct Visual Studio packages to be run in DEV and once promoted, they will need to run from Agent.